# What are the ways to attain Mukthi in present 21st century or generation of 2020 year in Kaliyuga

Tags: brahmins, mukti

What are the ways to attain Mukthi in present generation of 2020 year of 21st century in Kaliyuga for brahmachari brahmins?

Comment: the same ways as before are valid now.

Answer (score 0):

Great sage of present age shri Ram Krishna 's teaching is " Maner paap paap nai "means sin done in the mind is not actual sin. Until translated into action it does not become paap. If some mental sin has been committed that can be undone through virtuous deeds. The above saying of the great saint holds compete answer to your question in the context of kaliyug. Regards, Hare Krishna.